# Which SaaS product should we use to replace our custom-made email retrieval system?

Tags: email, php, saas, imap

Our app has a feture where we retrieve emails from one of our mailboxes to do data entry. We use PHP IMAP functions to handle all the processes, all good until recently we have more and more problems with parsing the emails, so much that we think it's not robust to keep maintaining it ourselves.

We were wondering if there any SaaS product out there that helps with this? In a nutshell, our process is:

- Users send emails to email files@example.com
- We build a function to fetch all the messages in that mailbox
- We extract the attachments and save them to our database

Our primary problem has always been dealing with email content from the users because each of them use a different email client to send the email, some even encrypt the attachment, etc. We need a more robust solution to help us handle this.

Comment: What types of encryptions do you need to support? Would the system have the keys and decrypt before storing to the database?

Comment: You store only attachments right, you don't attempt to parse the email's content. What metadata do you store?

Comment: Yeah we only store attachments and use the subject line as a guide to what to do with the attachments (where to save, which category, etc)

Comment: So you don't save the email address of the sender, for instance?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, no we don't save the email addresses, we read the emails for attachments and use the subject line to know where to put those attachments in our database

Comment: Could you please add all of these details in the body of your question (you can edit your question), including encryption details? Thanks!